# Override Ext.js sass/css variable without creating custom theme

Tags: css, extjs, sass, sencha-cmd

Is it possible to just change a few global css variables without creating a whole new theme or ui?

I'm trying to set e.g. `$form-field-border-width: 0 0 1px 0;` by creating `MyApp/sass/var/form/field/Base.scss` and just dropping the code.

I'm using Neptune and only have a few changes, so I'm trying to avoid creating a whole theme package.

Comment: do you have the all scss files setup? If so just override their vars and compile sass and that should work

Comment: What do you mean with scss files set up? I'm successfully adding custom css in MyApp/sass/etc, but I only manage to override variables if I create my own theme package.

Comment: When I had to override the base theme, that is what I did too. Basically set my variables I wanted to override then import their theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `sass` directory uses for store styles related to application components.
If you want to overwrite scss for core component (like *Ext.**) you should replace  *Sass* namespace in `app.json` file to:

```
"sass": {
    "namespace": ""
},
```

Be sure to store variables' files in `sass/var` directory. In your case path should be: `MyApp/sass/var/Ext/form/field/Base.scss`.